# TimerTask not executing task correctly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start 2 services in android. One service shall trigger a notification everyday at 10 AM and the other will have 3 tasks, first changing the value of the day when the clock strikes 12AM, and then at 12PM and 6PM respectively it will show a notification based on conditions.

To do this I'm using timertask and a timer. The service does run perfectly in the background but the task doesn't execute. At first I tried to do it by normally setting my Calendar to the required time but that was causing the tasks to execute as soon as I launched the app and invoked the services probably because its catching up on the day's timings which may have passed. so I tried to gave it a delay by adding 24hrs (i.e. 86400000 in milliseconds) to the timing for first execution.

Here's my code:

first service

```
public class reminder extends Service{

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
       /* NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tmcnotification);

        b.setContentTitle("TechMotherCare is Running");
        startForeground(1,b.build());*/
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "started 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, reminderresponse.class);


        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
      final  NotificationCompat.Builder n= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        n.setContentTitle("How are you feeling?");
        n.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tmcnotification);
        n.setContentText("Tap to open window.");
        n.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        n.setAutoCancel(true);
        final NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();

        final int time = now.getHourOfDay();
        final MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer().create(this,R.raw.tune);
       final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);




        //c.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

       Timer t = new Timer();
        Date w=c.getTime();

        TimerTask notify = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pl.start();
                mNotifyMgr.notify(1,n.build());


            }
        };
        //t.schedule(notify,c.getTime(),(1*60*60*1000));
        t.schedule(notify, new Date(w.getTime()+86400000),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));


    }
}
```

second service

```
public class messages extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    int daycount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

       final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int launchcount = sharedpreferences.getInt("launchcount", 0);
        sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("launchcount", ++launchcount).commit();

        final MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer().create(this,R.raw.tune);
        daycount = sharedpreferences.getInt("days", 0);
        Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        Calendar d= Calendar.getInstance();
        d.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
        d.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        d.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        Calendar e= Calendar.getInstance();
        e.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18);
        e.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        e.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        Timer p= new Timer();
        Timer q= new Timer();
       Timer r = new Timer();

        final TimerTask daychange = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             //   Toast.makeText(messages.this, "day changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("days",++daycount).commit();
                daycount=sharedpreferences.getInt("days",0);
                pl.start();
                if(daycount==1)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","وہ  مائیں جودباؤ،  اداسی اور گھبراہٹ کا شکار رہتی ہیں ان میں اتنی توانائی نہیں ہوتی کے وہ اپنی اور بچے کی صحت کا خیال رکھ سکیں۔").commit();
                }
                else if(daycount==2)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","کھیل ہی کھیل میں سیکھنا پلس ایک ایسا تربیتی پروگرام ہےجو ماں اور بچے کی صحت  اور ماں اور بچے کے آپس کے تعلقات پر مشتمل ہے۔ ").commit();
                }
                else if(daycount==3)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","کھیل ہی کھیل میں سیکھنا \" میں آپ کو ایسے طریقے بتائے جائیں گے جن کی مدد سے آپ بچے کی دماغی تحریک کو بڑھا سکتے ہیں اور بچوں کی نشونما کے عمل کو بہتر بنا سکتے ہیں۔").commit();
                }
                else if(daycount==4)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","تربیتی پروگرام  پیدائش سے 3 سال تک کے بچوں کے متعلق ہے۔  جس میں بچوں کی مصروفیات کو پانچ حصوں میں تقسیم کیا گیا ہے: 1  .اپنے وجود کا شعور ،2. جسمانی حرکات   3. باہمی تعلقات، 4.سمجھداری، 5.طریقہ بول چال.").commit();
                }
                else if(daycount==5)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","ماں کی ذہنی صحت کو بہتر بنانے کے لیے صحت مند سوچ کے تربیتی پروگرام کو استعمال کیا جائے گا۔").commit();
                }
                else if(daycount==6)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","غیر صحت مند سوچ ، غیر صحت مند جذبات اور رویوں کو جنم دیتی ہیں۔ آپ کی مدد کی جائے گی کہ کس طرح آپ اپنی سوچ کے منفی یا غیر صحت مند رخ کو پہچان کر اسے صحت مند سوچ میں بدل سکتی ہیں۔ ایسا کرنے سے آپ کو اداسی سے نکلنے میں مدد ملے گی۔").commit();
                }
               else if(daycount==7)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","اداسی  کی کیفیت کی مختلف علامات ہوتی ہیں جیسا کہ مایوسی، اداسی، کسی کام میں خوشی یادلچسپی کا محسوس نہ ہونا، چڑ چڑا پن، احساس کمتری، نیند کی کمی یا زیاتی، اور  خودکشی کے خیالات ").commit();
                }


               else if(daycount==8) //start of cbt and ltp message. so days counts as 1
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","پیدائش سے 2 ماہ تک کے بچے کو گود میں اٹھائیں۔ ایسا کرنے سے اس کی عادت خراب نہیں ہوگی بلکہ اسے تحفظ کا احساس ہوگا۔ ").commit();
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageatsix","ہمارے دکھ اور پریشانی کی وجہ ہمارے حالات اور ہمارے سوچنے کے طریقے ہوتے ہیں۔ ہم جذبات پر ذیادہ توجہ دیتے ہیں اس لیے ہم سوچوں سےآگاہ نہیں ہوتے۔ ").commit();
                }
                else if(daycount==9)
                {
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageattwelve","دن کے  خاص حصے  میں بچے کے ساتھ ہاتھ اور پاؤں پھیلانے کی ورزش کریں اس سے بچے کو سکون ملتا ہے۔").commit();
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putString("messageatsix","ہماری سوچیں عینک کے شیشوں کے رنگ کی  طرح ہیں اگر ہم سیاہ چشمے پہنتے ہیں تو ہمیں ہر چیز اندھیری نظر آئےگی۔ اگر ہم دنیا کو اس کے اصل رنگوں میں دیکھنا چاہتے ہیں تو عینک کے شیشوں کے بارے میں کچھ کرنا پڑے گا۔").commit();
                }

            }
        };
        Date d1=c.getTime();
        p.scheduleAtFixedRate(daychange,new Date(d1.getTime() + 86400000),(24*60*60*1000));
        Intent resultIntent1 = new Intent(this, showmessage12.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent1 =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent1,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        final  NotificationCompat.Builder n1= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        n1.setContentTitle("Aaj ka Paighaam");
        n1.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tmcnotification);
        n1.setContentText("Tap kr krke window kholiye.");
        n1.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent1);
        n1.setAutoCancel(true);
        final NotificationManager mNotifyMgr1 =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   final TimerTask msg1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(daycount>=1 && daycount<=77) {
                pl.start();
                mNotifyMgr1.notify(2,n1.build());
            }


        }
  };
  Date d2=d.getTime();

    q.scheduleAtFixedRate(msg1, new Date(d2.getTime() + 86400000), (24*60*60*1000));

    Intent resultIntent2 = new Intent(this, showmessage18.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent2 =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent2,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    final  NotificationCompat.Builder n2= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    n2.setContentTitle("Aaj ka dusra Paighaam");
    n2.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tmcnotification);
    n2.setContentText("Tap kr krke window kholiye.");
    n2.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent2);
    n2.setAutoCancel(true);
    final NotificationManager mNotifyMgr2 =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    final TimerTask msg2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(daycount>=8 && daycount<=77) {
                pl.start();
                mNotifyMgr2.notify(3,n2.build());
            }


        }
    };
    Date d3=e.getTime();

    r.scheduleAtFixedRate(msg2, new Date(d3.getTime() + 86400000), (24*60*60*1000));



}
```